# Bluetooth headset connects, but provides no audio input option

Tags: sound, bluetooth, skype

I have a bluetooth headset that I would like to use with Skype. It used to work perfectly a few Ubuntu versions ago. Then one day it stopped working, and it seems there were kernel bugs or something. I gave up on it for maybe half a year or more.

Recently, I thought I'd give it another go. On the upside, my headset seems to connect to my computer without any trouble:

[image: bluetooth_connected]

However, when I open Skype, it does not see the headset at all. There is only one Pulseaudio option, which is network sound server, not my headset.

[image: skype_no_headset]

The bluetooth headset also does not seem to appear anywhere in my sound settings.

[image: audio_no_headset]

How do I get Skype to recognize my bluetooth headset?

Comment: Is it possible to enable the headset within the Bluetooth Devices manager? (with right clicking, etc.)

Comment: @R110: I am not sure what you are asking. The headset is enabled, and sending and receiving data. In the first screenshot, the three coloured bars indicate it is connected. The problem is that it is not acting as a sound device after being enabled.

Comment: Did you try right clicking and then use Connect To: Audio Source?

Comment: @AmithKK: THere is no "Audio Source" option. There is only "Input Source" and "Headset Service". For years, I had used "Headset Service" without problem, so I assume that's the one that is supposed to work.

Comment: did you install package `pulseaudio-module-bluetooth`?

Comment: @titusjaka: It seems that module is already installed.

Comment: I have the same problem with my headset. But I also can't see it as output. The connection works and the sound worked in the past, but now I can not see it in the audio list or get the sound working on it. :-(